# How to fire dependent rules in drools xls decision table

Tags: jboss, drools, redhat

**PROBLEM :**
I have three rule tables in Decision Table (Spreadsheet) the rules of first two rule table defines which rule is to be fired from the third rule table. In First rule table according to some conditions, I have updated the fact and this fact is used to fire a rule from second rule table. And in ACTION column of second rule table I have updated the fact and I want to fire rules in 3rd Rule table based on this updated fact, but because of updated fact the rule from the first table fires again and then second and the loop goes on.

I can't find the way to add RuleFlow-Group in rule table whenever I add `RuleFlow-Group` the rules stops firing for any fact.

**WHAT I TRIED :**
I have added `No-Loop` to true so that no rules are firing of the same rule table for the updated fact.

I tried adding `LOCK-ON-ACTIVE` attribute, rules from the Rule Table 1 are working fine but no other rules are getting firing.
I think after firing the rule from Rule Table 1 it locks all the rule of the Rule Package instead, I am adding "lock-on-active" in Rule Table, not in Rule Set.

*Spread Sheet illustrating problem statement.*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very abstract set of rules, and I don't feel that it's worth discussing in depth. Updating a fact means it is re-evaluated wherever it occurs, which is in all rules. To avoid re-evaluation, use constraints that keep the rule from firing if the result of the RHS is already set in the fact.

```
rule "table_1_1"
when
    $input: Input(a==1, b!=1)
then
    modify( $input ){ setB( 1 ); }
end

rule "table_2_1"
when
    $input: Input(b==1, c!=1)
then
    modify( $input ){ setC( 1 ); }
end
```

The third table isn't using modify so it doesn't cause a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Adding condition can solve my problem but it is a small set of data which I have generated to define my problem but in my application, there are a lot of rule tables and all contains a lot of rules. Adding conditions will slow down the performance. I want to know is there any other option to do so.  And yes, the third table will not cause a loop.

Comment: Do you know how to add RuleFlow-Group or Agenda-Group in Spread Sheet decision Table